# Remix - How to add websocket to my project

Tags: websocket, netlify, remix.run

I started a indie stack project on remix.run and I would like to add websocket.io.
I would like to deploy in the future to Netlify. Could you please help me, I am new and do not really know what to do.

I found that it is possible to start a indie stack project with the "express" option but I do not know if it will be compatible with netlify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, [socket.io](https://socket.io/) requires a long-running server. A serverless environment such as Netlify functions won't work. There are ways to make websocket connections on AWS Lambda but I am not sure socket.io supports such configurations. Netlify and Vercel for sure don't (at this point).

For now, use Remix with the express adapter. Pick a stack that works with express and then you can simply integrate socket.io like you would on any other express server and React client project.

You can find a [great Remix with socket.io example](https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/socket.io) in the examples folder of Remix GitHub repository.

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/2465) about native websocket support in Remix. However, since websockets won't work on most serverless environments, it's unlikely at this moment that websockets will make it into Remix.

However, it seems like the Remix team is working on introducing Server-Sent-Events (SSE) to its fetch API. SSE can work as an alternative to websockets. Maybe that could be an alternative for future readers. You can find the discussion [here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/2622).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the detailed answer, that's awesome ! 
I will try what you explained and give a feedback !

Comment: I ended up using the simple remix example project with the express option. I added the socket code in my express server. Then, I added all the indie project pages in my current projet. (I failed to do the other way around since I lost the hot refresh). Then I deployed on Heroku and everything is working as expected. Thank you very much @Andre, you helped me a lot !